# Hibertate Criteria with Projections

Tags: java, hibernate

´m trying to aply a `Criteria.Restriction` to a query with `Projections`.

My code is:

```
ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("mId").as("mId"));
projections.add(Projections.property("mDate").as("mDate"));

Criteria criteria = mSession.createCriteria(MailAgroseguro.class)
    .add(Restrictions.between("mDate", dateMin, dateMax))
    .setProjection(projections)
    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(ObjectClass.class));
listObjectClass = (List<ObjectClass>)criteria.list();
```

Edit: 
The `ObjectClass.java`:

```
    public class ObjectClass {
        private Integer   mId;
        private String    mDate;
}
```

And the error is:

```
Hibernate: select this_.mId as y0_, this_.mDate as y1_ from objectclass this_ where y1_ between ? and ?
[INFO] 2014-11-21 16:59:24,554 - org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter -25221 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
[INFO] 2014-11-21 16:59:24,554 - org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter -25221 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Unknown column 'y1_' in 'where clause'
```

If I don´t add the `Restriction` or the `Projections` works fine!

Edited2: updated Error

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Format is a bit pls, most of your code is squashed. Secondly could you print your model also? Just field declaratins, without setters/getters.

Comment: Assuming you're using [samiandoni's AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer](https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer/blob/master/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer.java), your code works for me. Try logging the generated SQL by setting the `org.hibernate.SQL` category to `DEBUG`. Maybe that will give you a clue.

Comment: Yes, i´m using that class. pasted the error with the SQL

Comment: Where is 'mDate' declared & in which class, can you update relevant code.

Comment: Sorry changed MFechaRecepcion(in Spanish) to mDate(i´ve put this name to post)